# Commit Failed While Uploading My Plugin to Wordpress Plugin Repository

Tags: wordpress, svn, plugins, tortoisesvn, commit

My plugin got approved by WordPress, and I also got SVN repository URL.

I checkout out the plugin with Tortoise SVN, copied my plugin files to trunk folder but when I am trying to commit it, I am getting the following error.

```
Commit failed (details follow):

At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged

Server sent unexpected return value (400 Bad Request) in response to PROPPATCH
request for '/!svn/txn/747084-g5of'
```

I am new to SVN, am I doing it right?

How to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem, and what solved it for me was to do the initial SVN Checkout to my local directory using  **https**://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/[plugin-name] instead of **http**:// like I had been doing.

After that, I was able to commit new changes and create new tag versions.